# Using trasform:translate to center divs having problems with IE

Tags: html, css

When using

`width:100%;`

`height:100%;`

`position:absolute;`

`top:50%;`

`left:50%;`

`transform:translate(-50%, -50%);`

to center divs, it would make unnecessary blank space on IE. I assume it is because it ignores the transform cancellation of the space used by `top:50%` and `left:50%`

How do I solve this without having to use `overflow:hidden`?

EDIT - http://jsfiddle.net/ook2vnwm/

Comment: Transform works in IE9 and above. If you're seeing the problem in one of these, then you need to provide more information, like html, surrounding css, etc.

Comment: @bobdye I know that it works, what Im saying though is that the spaced used by using `left:50%` was never cancelled out by the `transform`, making it have an x-scrollbar. See edit for example, use IE...

Comment: Since you give your block w width of 100%, it is the same width as the window. So left: 50% moves it half-way across the window, and transformX moves it back to the left-hand edge. IE is apparently remembering the left: 50% and making the windows that wide, causing a scrollbar.

Comment: @bobdye yea, thats what Im tryna say the whole time, how do I get to fix this though? Without having to `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: There are lots of ways to do things,  but you don't give enough information to pick the right one. (1) Why are you trying to center a div with width: 100%? (2) Why does the div need to have position absolute? (3) Why is giving the surrounding element overflow: hidden a problem?